# Find account user is signed into - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm trying to make a to-do list website with login that shows a user different items depending on their account they're signed into. So for example, if someone signs in with an account that has the `_id` as, say, `12345` and writes down "do laundry" as their to-do list item, then when another user signs in with their account with the `_id` as `12346`, they won't be able to see the `do laundry` item that the first user wrote.

However, the problem right now is I can't figure out how to find the `_id` of the user that is currently signed in. I have something like this right now:

```
const accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
});

accountSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const Account = new mongoose.model("Account", accountSchema);

passport.use(Account.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  Account.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

// * MongoDB (Subject Page)

const subjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  subject: {
    id: String, // This is supposed to be equal to the _id of the account the user is using is signed into so that the website will check this id with the _id of the user is signed into, and then show or not show this to-do list item depending on if it matches or not
    subjectNames: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
});

const Subject = new mongoose.model("Subject", subjectSchema);

// ...

app.get("home", (req, res) => {
   if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        Account.find({}, (err, accountId) => { 
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(`accountid: ${accountId}`);
                Subject.find(
                    { subject: { id: accountId._id }},
                    (error, foundSubjects) => {
                        console.log(foundSubjects);
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        } else {
                            res.render("home", {
                                currentDate: dateTime.currentDate(),
                                weekday: dateTime.weekday(),
                                newSubjectItems: foundSubjects,
                            });
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
})

.post((req, res) => {
    const subject = req.body.newSubject;

    Account.find({}, (err, accountId) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(accountId._id);
            const subjectItem = new Subject({
                subject: {
                    id: accountId._id,
                    subjectNames: subject,
                },
            });

            subjectItem.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    if (err._message === "Syyyubject validation failed") {
                        res.redirect("/home");
                    }

                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    res.redirect("/home");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In the .post part, the id part doesn't work because I can't figure out how to find the _id of the account the user is signed into. Therefore, the .get part doesn't work as there is nothing in the `id` part in the subject schema.

How would I find the account that the user is signed into? I have looked at the documentation for passport.js but have I can't find anything related to this.

I have been unable to figure this out for a week now and would greatly appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I just had to put a simple `req.user.id` in the app.post("/home") route to get it working